# py2neo, neo4j defining node names from returning path object

Tags: neo4j, py2neo

I am querying a social network with nodes as Persons (with properties ID and Name) and relationships.
When I receive a Path object back it includes the (internal node id)-[Relationship]-(internal node id). For example
`code
'path': (abc123)-[:KNOW {prop1:'yxz'}]->(cef456)`

Is it possible to return a node property (ID or name) instead of the internal node id? I'm looking for a response like 

`'path': (Alice)-[:KNOW {prop1:'yxz'}]->(Bob)`

If not - is there a different way to do so not in py2neo?

I don't mind to load the data again  into neo4j (I'm using the `neo4j-admin import` module).

Any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: What is the Cypher query you are using?

Comment: I managed to solve the problem by iterating on the path object.